# ASP.NET Web API 2 - thrown Exception not in response body in Release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

In my Web API 2 project, I will do something like this:

`throw new Exception("Error message here.");`

In Visual Studio (in Release mode) on my local machine with IIS Express, it properly returns a response with the exception JSON in the body. But on the production server, it does not. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere? Perhaps on the server's IIS?

Comment: You can have a try in release mode on your local machine with IIS Express

Comment: My apologies, I actually was running it in Release mode on my local machine. Question has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the web.config to get this message when runing ASP.NET at IIS.

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="Off">
 </customErrors>
 <!-- Other configurations... -->
</system.web>
```